# How to make opencms and servlet working?

Tags: servlets, opencms

I'm having an issue trying to implement kaptcha.jar (https://code.google.com/p/kaptcha/) into opencms.

I added the jar and it's correctly loaded as in my jsp I have:

```
<%@ page import="com.google.code.kaptcha.servlet.KaptchaServlet" %>
<%
KaptchaServlet test = new KaptchaServlet();
String temp = test.getClass().getSimpleName();
%>
<div> Test : <%=test%></div>
```

Which is displaying:

```
Test : com.google.code.kaptcha.servlet.KaptchaServlet@14b1fda
```

So I think the jar is loaded (I might be wrong though).

In my web.xml, I added this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Kaptcha</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.code.kaptcha.servlet.KaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Kaptcha</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/kaptcha.test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Restarted my server, and tried to access the following URLs, always getting a 404/page does not exist:

- localhost/kaptcha.test
- localhost/opencms/kaptcha.test
- localhost/opencms/opencms/kaptcha.test
- localhost:8080/kaptcha.test
- localhost:8080/opencms/kaptcha.test
- localhost:8080/opencms/opencms/kaptcha.test

What I am doing wrong?
Why is my servlet not working?

I tried the jar in a custom dynamic web project in eclipse, it works perfectly.
In this project, when I access /kaptcha.test, an image is displayed, changing everytime I refresh the page.

Thanks for your help.

Note: I'm using OpenCMS 7.0

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the zip from https://code.google.com/p/kaptcha/downloads/detail?name=kaptcha-2.3.2.zip ??

If you do, you will see a .war file in the zip.

If you install and setup Apache Tomcat correctly,
you can just place the war file in the Web Apps directory and the sample will be
installed for you auto-magically.......

Then you can see from there, how to structure the web app in an eclipse project.